# HTML, :hover css menu and accessibility

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have a question.

I have made a css menu (no javascript required). This relies on a:hover to show or hide UL elements within the A.

using visibility:hidden; and visibility:visible;

So far so good, until I try and use only a keyboard.

Now to be accessible I need to be able to navigate solely with the keyboard.

So I also added the a:focus to the classes that control the visibilty.

This however did not fix the menu and it remains closed.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this to keep my site accessible?

Thanks in advance.

**edit** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YDaV9/3/)

The biggest problem is how to achieve this so they can tab on the links below.
I can do it for mouse only, not for keyboard only.

Someone must know how to do this?!

Comment: Please post a html snippet and the base css you are using for expanding the menu.

Comment: Or even better a jsFiddle snippet so we don't have to copy/paste it to check it out.

Comment: "This relies on a:hover to show or hide UL elements **within** the A." - Block elements like `ul` are not allowed inside inline elements like `a`. Other than that, you're right to use `:focus`.

Comment: The ul is outside the a, have updated the jsfiddle to what it should have been.

Comment: It works now with keyboard TAB. The submenu shows in the fiddle after you changed your selector in the above edit. in IE9 and FF4.0.1

Comment: try tabbing into the links under the first one, as the anchor loses focus the menus disappear

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pure css based :hover menues are not typically very user friendly even using a mouse. Since the as soon as the pointer is one pixel outside the menu, it's no longer hovered and disappears. This can be very annoying, especially for people with poor fine motor control.

I would suggest you use javascript to show and hide the sub menues, adding a delay so the menu does not disappear too fast if you just happen to move outside the menu for a moment (or use click activated and click hidden menu may be even better). Make sure that the menu is not hidden for users not using JavaScript (make submenus visible by default and hide them using javascript onLoad).

**Edit 1:** And of course you write the java script to respond both to click/hover and focus.

**Edit 2:**
If you design the page first to work without javascript or css selectors such as :hover, e.g. the menu and the sub-menus are visible all the time. Then add javascript that hides the submenu on document load, and toggles the sub-menus on click / on focus etc. It will automatically work for users not using javascript.

If the design does not work well with all the submenus visible (e.g. they are overlapping or something like this), you could also make a static version (the one visible without javascript) designed to work well even when fully visible, and replace it with a more complex javascript controlled menu when the javascript loads. Or you could let the top level menu items (those always visible in the dynamic version) links that send a query parameter to the server that toggle the specific menu item on and off serverside, and the javascript removes the `href` value from the links and adds listeners to open and close the submenus without the server roundtrip. It depends on how large the menus are what would be most sensible.

Comment: I was beginning to lean down this road.... do you not need to cater for the folks out there that do not use javascript though? Or as it is something that they actively turn off should I not care??

Comment: Have accepted this answer as the best I am going to get, and I agree with it in principle. I can't award the bounty yet, another 21 hours and I can. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer as to *why* this happens is that you've styled the sub-menu to appear when the `a` is focused. If you tab *from* the `a` element the `a` is *no longer focused*, and therefore the sub-menu disappears again (as per the selector/declarations).

As for a fix, I'll have to think about that; sorry not to be more immediately useful.

---

**Edited** in response to question from OP (in comments):

> ...the question is really, how do you do this to make it accessible?

Unfortunately, I can't think of a non-JavaScript means to achieve accessibility, I'm afraid. At this time CSS doesn't allow for the selection of parents or siblings (which could make it work, if `.subnav a:focus parent(li) siblings` was a valid selector).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know and understand that is the problem, but I if you tab from one to the other, you will not have focus on any element. So the question is really, how do you do this to make it accessible?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this, is it even possible?

Comment: I don't know; I don't flatter myself to believe I know all there is to know, but I can't think of a way making it possible, so far. Though I keep coming back to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, and I might be wrong, that it has to do with the specificity. Usually the order in which the dynamic pseudo classes are styled, effects the rule precendence.

```
a:link /*for unvisited links, mutually exclusive to :visit*/
a:visted /*for visited links, mutually exclusive to :link*/
a:focus /*for focused elements such as selection by accesskey using keyboard*/
a:hover /*for elements in the state of being hovered upon by mouse*/
a:active /*for elements that are in the state of being activiated*/
```

The above is just one of the possible order depending upon the effect you want to acheive and they have different specificity. I suspect your order is interfering and because of specificity, your styles are not being applied. HTML and CSS for the same will be helpful to dig out the problem.

[Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclasses)

Comment: I have heard this, but think this is only the case with older browsers.

Comment: No, I dont think so. Modern browser behave the same as well. I stand to be corrected. In any case, the provided HTML and CSS can resolve the issue, if the above is teh case or not.

Comment: This is true, but has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [pure CSS solution](http://jsbin.com/ojera6).
Tested and **working** on Chrome 11, Firefox 2, Opera 9.5, Safari 4, IE8 and IE9.
I discovered to my dismay that using [`:active`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-active) (instead of `:focus`) with the sibling selectors (adjacent or general) isn't supported by IE7.

Comment: This uses Javascript, which is not what I was looking for.

Comment: @jimplode Are you serious!? Could you tell me where you see javascript used? It's a pure CSS solution. Copy/paste the [code](http://jsbin.com/ojera6/edit). You can use it with JS turned off.

Comment: @jimplode **it's working on IE8** and probably on IE9 too. But the old and deprecated IE6 and IE7 [don't support](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-focus) the :focus pseudo-class so you will have to provide a javascript alternative for them.

Comment: doesn't work at all in ie9 for me, and in ie8 the links disappear when tabbing.

Comment: @jimplode I can't test on IE9 sorry. Again on IE8 all links are accessible through tabbing.

Comment: only the first time of tabbing, not after.

Comment: Your solution does not work, let the people out there try it themselves. I have not said a bad word about you, and the first thing you sent did not work when I had javascript turned off. Maybe was just the site you chose to put it on!! So don't say I have the attitude problem when you solutions just do not work. This is about making things accessible to everyone, and how to do that, your solution only works for newer browsers or some other version of ie8 that I clearly do not have. Thank you for your effort, but your solution is just not viable, or a solution at all.